# store data in memory with nestjs

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I am trying to persist some data in my nestjs server so I can then use that data in my client app through http requests.

I have created a products.service.ts file with the function `getAllData()` that fetch some data and creates a new array that is assigned to the variable `products` (which is the data I'm trying to persist). This function is called when the app is initialized (I know this works because when I run the app the `console.log(this.products)` inside the function shows data.

This is my products.service.ts code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class ProductsService {
  private products: any[] = [];

  getProducts(): any[] {
    //empty
    console.log(this.products); 
    return this.products;
  }

  async getAllProducts(): Promise<any[]> {
    const categories = await this.getProductsCategories();
    const productsPromises = categories.categories.map(async (category) => {
        const products = await this.getProductsByCategory(category.strCategory);
        const modifiedProducts = products.meals.map((product) => {
            ....
        });
        return modifiedProducts;
      });
      
      const products = await Promise.all(productsPromises);
      const flattenedProducts = products.flat();

      this.products = flattenedProducts;
      //shows data
      console.log(this.products) 
      
      return flattenedProducts;
    }

  async getProductsCategories(): Promise<any>{
    try{
      const apiURL = 'https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/categories.php';
      const apiResponse = await fetch(apiURL);
      const categories = await apiResponse.json(); 

      return categories;
    }
    catch(e){
      throw new Error('Error while fetching products');
    }
  }
  async getProductsByCategory(category: string): Promise<any> {
    try {
      const apiURL = `https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?c=${category}`;
      const apiResponse = await fetch(apiURL);
      const products = await apiResponse.json();

      return products;
    } catch (e) {
      throw new Error('Error while fetching products by category');
    }
  }
}
```

The function `getProducts()` is called in my products.controller.ts file when an http request is done in the route '/products' but the products array is empty:

```
import { Controller, Get, Param } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ProductsService } from './products.service';

@Controller('products')
export class ProductsController {
    constructor(private readonly ProductsService: ProductsService) {}

 @Get('/')
    async getAllProducts(): Promise<any[]> {
        const products = await this.ProductsService.getProducts();

        return products;
     }
 }
```

Any idea why the products variable is empty when I make the request ? It should have the data created with `getAllProducts()` as this function is called onModuleInit

**UPDATE 1**:

I'll add the products.module.ts where I call `getAllProducts()` onModuleInit:

```
import { Module, OnModuleInit } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ProductsController } from './products.controller';
import { ProductsService } from './products.service';

@Module({
    controllers: [ProductsController],
    providers: [ProductsService],
})

export class ProductsModule implements OnModuleInit {
    constructor(private readonly productsService: ProductsService) {}
  
    async onModuleInit() {
      await this.productsService.getAllProducts();
    }
}
```

Then I import and use this module at app.module.ts file:

```
import { ProductsModule } from './products/products.module';
...

@Module({
  imports: [ProductsModule],
  controllers: [AppController, ProductsController],
  providers: [AppService, ProductsService],
})

export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Where do you call the `ProductsService#getAllProducts` method that populates `this.products`?

Comment: I will add that code to the question, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add the `ProductsController` and `ProductsService` to the `AppModule`. You essentially have two "versions" of the `ProductsController` and `ProductsService` being instantiated, and Nest is calling the one that *didn't* run the `onModuleInit` from the `ProductsModule`. Remove them from the `AppModule` it and should all work.